# Can Apache Zeppelin use a Dataset<Row> created by another application?

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

I have created an application that cleans and enriches some data from files, and at a time they are available in the form of a `Dataset<Row>`.

In my ideal world, `Apache Zeppelin` would be able to grab it, I would only create a notebook and then easily gain data visualizations for the end-users.

I tried `Apache Zeppelin` as a demo but I've never been really inside of it. Can it do what I'm expecting ?

Or will it be mandatory for my application to store it's results from the `Dataset<Row>` it creates to some parquet files, and then `Apache Zeppelin` on its side, should reloading that data from those parquet files into it's *Spark* sessionContext ?

You understand that I would like to avoid such step !

Has `Apache Zeppelin` the ability to catch "a third party Dataset" and use it, provided it has been created by the same `Apache Spark` version it is using ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Apache Ignite](https://ignite.apache.org/use-cases/spark-acceleration.html) for it.

> Apache Ignite provides an implementation of the Spark RDD, which
>   allows any data and state to be shared in memory as RDDs across Spark
>   jobs. The Ignite RDD provides a shared, mutable view of the data
>   stored in Ignite caches across different Spark jobs, workers, or
>   applications.
>
> Ignite supports DataFrame APIs allowing Spark to write to and read
>   from Ignite through that interface. Furthermore, Ignite analyses
>   execution plans produced by Spark's Catalyst engine and can execute
>   parts of the plan on Ignite nodes directly, which will reduce data
>   shuffling and consequently make your SparkSQL perform better.

Also, [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FnVCHJPmPkw&feature=emb_logo) is a great video which explains how to use Apache Ignite.

Comment: So it means it that I should link my application with `Apache Ignite`, and then it's `Apache Ignite` that I will link with `Apache Zeppelin` or order to make `Apache Zeppelin` able to  query dynamically my application and produce data visualiazation for it ? Application <-> Ignite <-> Zeppelin ?

Comment: Yes, I think it's a way to go.